# PDO deleting records from multiple tables using joins

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, inner-join

i want to delete a table row with a photo table. there is also a table called photo_translate where i store my alt text in different languages. is this possible using joins?

```
$query=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM photo,photo_tranlate INNER JOIN photo_translate on photo.id=photo_translate.rec_id WHERE photo.rec_id=? and photo.page=?" );
    $query->bindvalue(1,$rec_id);
    $query->bindvalue(2,$page_id);
    $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set a [foreign key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) with "on delete cascade" on the field *photo_translate.rec_id*

This way when you delte the record in the "photo" table, the corrisponding record in the "photo_translate" table will be deleted automatically.

This is the correct way to handle this situation